# Select named range starting with the same first letters

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple named ranges on the same sheet.I would like to unhide at the click of a button all those ranges with VBA. example of named range: April_name1 . the 2nd on the same sheet is April_name2. So all the ranges start with the same code in front: April_ .

How can i loop through all ranges that start with April_ and unhide them?

Someone else has already asked a similar question on here ([VBA Excel select named range starting with character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514085/vba-excel-select-named-range-starting-with-character)) and I think their code answer,amended for my scenario above, would be as follows:

```
Sub April_button_Click()

Dim NamedRange As Name

For Each NamedRange In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If UCase(Left(NamedRange.Name, 6)) = "April_" Then
               Range(NamedRange.RefersTo).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next NamedRange

  End Sub
```

I don't want to create a duplicate question but my code above does not run at all when I click the button, not even an error message. Any clue? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using UCase the wrong way 
UCASE Left never will be April_ , Only can be APRIL (ucase) so swap the code

```
For Each NamedRange In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If UCase(Left(NamedRange.Name, 6)) = "APRIL_" Then
               Range(NamedRange.RefersTo).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next NamedRange
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: the named ranges in my example start as 'April_'. Does it matter that the first letter is in capital?

Answer (score 0):

See below.

```
Sub April_button_Click()

Dim NamedRange As Name


For Each NamedRange In ThisWorkbook.Names
    'get value for sheet reference
    SheetValue = Split(Split(CStr(NamedRange), "!", -1)(0), "=", -1)(1)
    '
    If UCase(Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetValue).Range(NamedRange).Value, 6)) = "APRIL_" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetValue).Range(NamedRange).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

Next NamedRange



End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thanks. Sorry, do I need to make any changes to your code above?

Comment: the way it is above, I get an error saying 'Run Time error 9. Subscript out of range'

Comment: No, this should work for sure. I just tested it on multiple sheets as well. Maybe you can try changing this, although it should not make a difference. Are you sure you are receiving an error on the code below, and not on some other part? Which row of code gives you this runtime error?

ThisWorkbook.names - > ActiveWorkbook.names

Comment: when I click to debug after the runtime error, the following line gets highlighted in yellow: Dim NamedRange As Name


For Each NamedRange In ThisWorkbook.Names
    'get value for sheet reference
    SheetValue = Split(Split(CStr(NamedRange), "!", -1)(0), "=", -1)(1)
    '
    If UCase(Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetValue).Range(NamedRange).Value, 6)) = "APRIL_" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetValue).Range(NamedRange).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

Next NamedRange



I've tried again still same issue..

Comment: can I attach a screenshot if it helps? not sure how though

Comment: you can by using: ![Valid XHTML](http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10).

Comment: in 'This Workbook' I have the following code that makes sure that those named ranges (plus others for May, June etc) are automatically hidden when closing the workbook so that the user can open the workbook and then only unhide the April columns:  Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Columns("W:LI").Hidden = True
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Comment: check the learn more about comments and scroll down to images. you cna input your own url for a picture i guess. you can upload one to tinypic or something similair

Comment: if I click your link for attaching a screenshot it just opens a blank web page. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192872/discussion-between-elena-and-kolin-chang).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
Sub April_button_Click()

Dim NamedRange As Name

    For Each NamedRange In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If Len(NamedRange.Name) >= 6 And UCase(Left(NamedRange.Name, 6)) = "APRIL_" Then
            NamedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next NamedRange

End Sub
```

Maybe a bit easier to read if we expand it like this and add some educational comments:

```
Sub April_button_Click()

Dim NamedRange As Name
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nameRng As Range

    For Each NamedRange In ThisWorkbook.Names

        ' To avoid any errors from the LEFT function, we add a Len-check to make sure we only call
        ' LEFT if the name is long enough to contain what we are looking for
        If Len(NamedRange.Name) >= 6 And UCase(Left(NamedRange.Name, 6)) = "APRIL_" Then

            ' First we find what worksheet we "need" to qualify our call with
            ' We do this by asking the named range what is the index of the worksheet the range it
            '    contains
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(NamedRange.RefersToRange.Worksheet.Index)

            ' Second we find what the local range is
            ' We do this by asking the named range what local range it contains
            Set nameRng = ws.Range(NamedRange.RefersToRange.Address)

            ' Now we can just use our range from before:
            nameRng.EntireRow.Hidden = False

            ' Which means the same as this:
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(NamedRange.RefersToRange.Worksheet.Index).Range(NamedRange.RefersToAddress).EntireRow.Hidden = False

            ' And you'll notice that all the declarations in the previous line come from NamedRange itself
            ' That's because NamedRange is already fully qualified!
            ' So the above statement is equal to this also:
            NamedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next NamedRange

End Sub
```

What tripped up your original code was wrong usage of `UCASE`. `UCASE` will convert its entire argument into upper-case, so `UCase("april_")` does not become `April_`, it becomes `APRIL_`. Your code was performing the comparison `"APRIL_ = April_"`, which returns `False`.